# hdfsFileStatus and FileStatus difference

Tags: apache, hadoop

what is the main difference between the 2 classes. 
mainly, what situation would i use one and not the other?

org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol package
http://www.sching.com/javadoc/hadoop/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/protocol/HdfsFileStatus.html

org.apache.hadoop.fs package
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html

Answer (score 1):

`HdfsFileStatus` is marked with `@InterfaceAudience.Private` and `@InterfaceStability.Evolving` annotations (check the source code). The first annotation means it intended to be used for internal Hadoop implementations. The second annotation means the file might be changing (backwards compatible support might not be available between releases). Basically you should not use `HdfsFileStatus` in your code.